# Unable to connect to MongoDB Atlas using Mongoose in Express

Tags: express, mongoose, graphql

I am trying to connect to MongoDB atlas using mongoose but always get an error,

I have tried to change my ip address and also try to change the link 
also change all the settings in mongoDB altas but always get the same error

```
const express = require('express')
const graphqlHTTP = require('express-graphql')
const app = express()
const catSchema = require('./Schema/categorySchema')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

// SetUp MongoDB 
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://khawar111:khawar111@e-selling-bh1wv.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority', { useNewUrlParser: true })
mongoose.connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('Database Connected')
})
mongoose.connection.on('error', (e) => {
    console.log(e)
})

// Set Route for GraphQL 

app.use('/graphQL', graphqlHTTP({
    schema: catSchema,
    graphiql: true
})

)


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server Started')
})
```

Error:

```
Error: queryTxt ETIMEOUT e-selling-bh1wv.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:203:19) {
  errno: 'ETIMEOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEOUT',
  syscall: 'queryTxt',
  hostname: 'e-selling-bh1wv.mongodb.net'
}
(node:25313) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: queryTxt ETIMEOUT e-selling-bh1wv.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:203:19)
(node:25313) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:25313) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually,you need to remove " test?retryWrites=true&w=majority " from your connection string and replace it with the name of your database.Like this

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://khawar111:khawar111@e-selling-bh1wv.mongodb.net/DatabaseName', { useNewUrlParser: true })
```

this is because "test?retryWrites=true&w=majority" is used for testing purposes

Comment: Have you whitelist all IP addresses, if not u won't be able to connect to your database.Also, crosscheck your username and password .IP whitelist is in atlas settings

Comment: found the solution the problem was i was using older version of node driver

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to change the node version to 2.2.12

[image]

And add IP address like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I faced the issue and I try to find the answer but nothing works then after some time it works normally again . I think it is just a connection limit issue.